# How to trace which data field of XML file consuming more response in IBM websphere?

Tags: websphere, mdm

When i process the file in soapui it's taking 38 secs of response in websphere application hosted server... How to trace out which data field in XML file consuming more response time as response time out is 10 sec but usually it's taking 35 sec ... Please help out

I tried enabling detailed trace under logs and trace in websphere